# changing textView's layout gravity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

I have a `TextView` in a `ListView`. I am trying to change the alignment of the `textview` according to the corresponding text. But it is not working.

Thanks

```
if (stringItem != null) {
        TextView messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);

         if (mine==0)
             messageText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);            

         if (mine==1)    
             messageText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

     messageText.setText(stringItem);   
}
```

and my Layout is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/self_textview"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT: ** I know how to change it from the `xml` file, but how to change it from code ?

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Comment: can you post the result in logcat ?

Comment: I dont get any errors but its not setting the alignment. All of the messages are being shown the same way.

Comment: take a look at varibale " mine " initialised or not ?

Comment: ohh, I guess the text is getting set in the right matter. but i want the whole textview to start from right to left, instead of left to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by changing the `layoutParams` of a `linearlayout` and changing its `gravity` then setting it to the `textview`.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams para=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
             para.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
             messageText.setLayoutParams(para);
```

will change the textview's gravity to right.

Comment: That's because this is changing the layout_gravity, not gravity

Comment: Yea that's exactly what it is, is that a bad practice or something ?

Comment: No not at all, I was just pointing out the difference, I was really confused by gravity and layout gravity for a while it still takes some tinkering. The reason why you're original code worked in xml because it was setting the layout_gravity, the reason why the java code failed was because it was setting gravity

Comment: Exactly. And that's why i updated my java code to change the `layout gravity`.

Answer (score 1):

set the textview width to match_parent, Gravity sets how things are laid out INSIDE of the view, so if you set the textview's width to the list view items width and then set the gravity of the textview it will align the actual text there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/self_textview"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I also noticed you have the gravity set on the linear layout. I would not try to mix gravity and layout_gravity just stick to one. You might also get the desired effect by setting the gravity of the linear layout instead of the text view